# save() prohibited to prevent data loss due to unsaved related object 'postid'

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a database (and model) situation like shown in the following schema:

[image: Database diagram]

this is the ModelSerialize:

```
class PostCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    base64image = serializers.CharField(allow_blank=True, required=False)
    categories = serializers.ListField(child=serializers.IntegerField(), required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('title', 'text', 'base64image', 'categories')

    def create(self, validated_data):
       cats = None
       if 'categories' in validated_data:
           cats = validated_data.pop('categories')

       post = Post.objects.create(**validated_data)

       if cats is not None:
           for cat in cats:
               PostCategory.objects.create(postid=post, categoryid=Category.objects.get(id=cat), isprimary=False)

       return post
```

I'm sending this json to the api method

```
{
"title": "Post Test",
"text": "Body post Test",
"categories": [2,4]
}
```

but i got this error:

```
ValueError: save() prohibited to prevent data loss due to unsaved related object 'postid'.

Internal Server Error: /api/post/create/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/alfdev/Lavori/PushApp/Rumorize/rvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 149, in get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Users/alfdev/Lavori/PushApp/Rumorize/rvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 147, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/alfdev/Lavori/PushApp/Rumorize/rvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 58, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/alfdev/Lavori/PushApp/Rumorize/rvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 68, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/alfdev/Lavori/PushApp/Rumorize/rvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 466, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/Users/alfdev/Lavori/PushApp/Rumorize/rvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 463, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/alfdev/Lavori/PushApp/Rumorize/rvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rest_framework/generics.py", line 192, in post
    return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/alfdev/Lavori/PushApp/Rumorize/rvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py", line 21, in create
    self.perform_create(serializer)
  File "/Users/alfdev/Lavori/PushApp/Rumorize/server/rumorize/contents/views.py", line 117, in perform_create
    PostCategory.objects.create(postid=x, categoryid=Category.objects.get(id=cat), isprimary=False)
  File "/Users/alfdev/Lavori/PushApp/Rumorize/rvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 122, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/alfdev/Lavori/PushApp/Rumorize/rvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 401, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "/Users/alfdev/Lavori/PushApp/Rumorize/rvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 651, in save
    "unsaved related object '%s'." % field.name
ValueError: save() prohibited to prevent data loss due to unsaved related object 'postid'.
```

My post_create implementation in view:

```
def perform_create(self, serializer):
# build and save the image
if 'base64image' in serializer.validated_data:
    base64_string = serializer.validated_data.pop('base64image')
    import base64
    import os
    import uuid

    base64_format, base64_string = base64_string.split(';base64,')
    base64_content = base64.b64decode(base64_string)
    filename = '{}{}'.format(uuid.uuid4(), utilities.file_extension_from_base64_format(base64_format))
    path = os.path.join(MEDIA_ROOT, 'post_photos')

    if not os.path.exists(path):
        os.makedirs(path)

    with open(os.path.join(path, filename), 'wb+') as f:
        f.write(base64_content)

    serializer.validated_data['image'] = filename

serializer.save(userid=self.request.user, updateuserid=self.request.user, state=1)
```

**UPDATE**

now i got this error:
django.db.models.fields.related_descriptors.RelatedObjectDoesNotExist: Post has no id.

these are my models:

```
class Post(models.Model):
id = models.BigIntegerField(db_column='ID', primary_key=True, editable=False)
title = models.CharField(db_column='Title', max_length=500)
text = models.TextField(db_column='Text')
createdate = models.DateTimeField(db_column='CreateDate', editable=False, default=datetime.datetime.now)
updatedate = models.DateTimeField(db_column='UpdateDate', blank=True, null=True, editable=False, default=datetime.datetime.now)
updateuserid = models.ForeignKey(User, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='UpdateUserID', blank=True, null=True, related_name='PostUpdateUser')
userid = models.OneToOneField(User, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='UserID', related_name='creation_user')
image = models.CharField(db_column='Image', max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
state = models.SmallIntegerField(db_column='State')

class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'post'
    verbose_name = 'Post'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Posts'
```

class PostCategory(models.Model):
    id = models.BigIntegerField(db_column='ID', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    postid = models.ForeignKey(Post, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='PostID', related_name='posts_categories')  # Field name made lowercase.
    categoryid = models.ForeignKey(Category, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='CategoryID')  # Field name made lowercase.
    isprimary = models.BooleanField(db_column='IsPrimary')  # Field name made lowercase. This field type is a guess.

```
class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'post_category'
```

any suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: It feels like your code here doesn't match the error. You get the error because the post was saved which contradicts the Post.objects.create.

Comment: would you explain better what are you mean?

Comment: if my approach is not the right one, tell me please how i can save Post instance and related Categories?

Comment: Sorry, the above comment has a typo. What I meant is that you get the error because the post is *not* saved which contradicts the `Post.objects.create` line.

Comment: ok i understand the error, but have you a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Try to call the `create` method of `ModelSerializer` instead of creating the object on your own. Also the if statement is not necessary and for PostCategory you can use the `id` fields directly.

```
class PostCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    base64image = serializers.CharField(allow_blank=True, required=False)
    categories = serializers.ListField(child=serializers.IntegerField(), required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('title', 'text', 'base64image', 'categories')

    def create(self, validated_data):

       # you don't need the if block
       cats = validated_data.pop('categories', None)

       # try calling the create method of ModelSerializer
       post = super(PostCreateSerializer, self).create(validated_data)

       if cats is not None:
           for cat in cats:
               PostCategory.objects.create(postid_id=post.id, categoryid_id=cat, isprimary=False)

       return post
```

Comment: Do you use transactions?

Comment: No, i don't use transactions

Comment: Strange. Is this really the full code you have? Can you add the full traceback to your question?

Comment: Please add your `perform_create` method. The error seems to be there: `/Users/alfdev/Lavori/PushApp/Rumorize/server/rumorize/contents/views.py", line 117`

Comment: in the view i've forgotten a test that causes the old exception, now i got this error: django.db.models.fields.related_descriptors.RelatedObjectDoesNotExist: Post has no id.

Comment: i found a workaround: PostCategory.objects.create(postid=Post.objects.last(), categoryid_id=cat, isprimary=False) but i think is not the right way to deal with relation.